# Add client certificate in socket connection

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

I am stuck with this problem since last few days but could not get any solution.

I am using net php-epp client and here is my code...

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'ssl'=>array(
            'local_cert'=> dirname(__FILE__).'/cert.pem',
            'passphrase' => dirname(__FILE__).'/key.pem',
        )
    )
);

$greeting = $client->connect($host, $port, $timeout, $ssl, $context);
echo $greeting;
```

I am getting following error...

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file
```

And before you ask `key.pem` starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `cert.pem` starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

However i can connect using...

```
openssl s_client -connect epp.dom.net:700 -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

This command shows connected, so does that mean my certificates are fine?

Please someone help me to fix this. Please

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php), the private key must be specified in the `local_pk` stream context option. The `passphrase` option (which you are currently using) is necessary when the private key file itself was encrypted with a passphrase:

> **`local_pk` string**
>
> Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for certificate (local_cert) and private key.
>
> **`passphrase` string**
>
> Passphrase with which your local_cert file was encoded.

This means your stream context should be initialized like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'local_cert' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cert.pem',
        'local_pk' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/key.pem',
    )
));
```

---

Alternatively, you can also concatenate certificate and private key into one file and use the `local_cert` option only (plus a `passphrase` option if -- and only if -- your private key is encrypted with a passphrase).

Comment: Thanks helmbert, you are awesome man. Thanks a lot. I am so happy. Happy Holiday, are you available for some small projects?

Comment: is there any way/email to contact you?